# HTML Table: How to position div absolutely across multiple cells in tr

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create the behavior in a html table cell to where I can absolutely position a div inside a html table tr like the image below and only have the absolutely positioned content appear on hover of the row. This content will appear in each row when hovered on. This would need work for each row of the table when hovered

[image: Absolutely positioned div inside html table]

My structure more or less looks like..

```
<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col>
    <col>
    <col>
  </colgroup>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 1</td>
    </tr>
      <td>Cell 2</td>
    <tr>
    </tr>
     <td>Cell 3</td>
    <tr>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
<table/>
```

If I try to position any other divs inside the tr, its shifts the content over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can combine hover and after pseudo selector

the css

```
tbody > tr:hover::after{
        content: "absolute positioned content";
        position: absolute;
        display: inline;
        left: 150px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
        background-color: red;
        border: 1px solid black;
      }
```

full html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
      tbody > tr:hover::after{
        content: "absolute positioned content";
        position: absolute;
        display: inline;
        left: 150px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
        background-color: red;
        border: 1px solid black;
      }
      .table_wrapper {
      position: relative;
      width: max-content;
    }

    .my_table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    .my_table :where(tr, th, td) {
      border: 1px solid gray;
      padding: 20px 50px;
      background-color: whitesmoke;
    }

  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <table class="my_table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>head 1</th>
        <th>head 2</th>
        <th>head 3</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1, 1</td>
        <td>Cell 1, 2</td>
        <td>Cell 1, 3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 2, 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2, 2</td>
        <td>Cell 2, 3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 3, 1</td>
        <td>Cell 3, 2</td>
        <td>Cell 3, 3</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This works 99% for me. Not sure why in my instance it is pushing the content to the side, but your snippet it looks good.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.table_container {
  position: relative;
  width: max-content;
}

.my_table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.my_table :where(tr, th, td) {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 20px 50px;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}

.my_table tr {
  position: relative;
}

.my_absolute_content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  padding: 10px 50px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.my_table tr:hover .my_absolute_content {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<table class="my_table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>head 1</th>
      <th>head 2</th>
      <th>head 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 1, 1</td>
      <td>Cell 1, 2</td>
      <td>Cell 1, 3</td>
      <td class="my_absolute_content">
        absolute content
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 2, 1</td>
      <td>Cell 2, 2</td>
      <td>Cell 2, 3</td>
      <td class="my_absolute_content">
        absolute content
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 3, 1</td>
      <td>Cell 3, 2</td>
      <td>Cell 3, 3</td>
      <td class="my_absolute_content">
        absolute content
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This wouldn't work for my scenario. I need it to appear on each row, not the whole table as a whole